# Is there any formula to create a hyperlink in an excel to another sheet?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

Here is what i exactly need to do.

I have an excel workbook with many sheets. I need to work on two sheets- Attributes_Master and Domain_Details.

Both have a field in commmon - **Domain** but not in same order.

I need to add a hyperlink in **Domain** column of **Attributes_master** to Domain column of Domain_master. There are around 50,000 entries in that column.

I know that I can get to know the cell address in domain_master by using `MATCH()` function.
Any shortcut to get the hyperlink done quickly?

Comment: What does the hyperlink link to? Do you want to link to the cell in the other sheet that has the same domain as the current row?

Comment: Yes,exactly! But the order of data in that column is not in same order in both the sheets,and can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel Hyperlink() function takes string arguments. You can build the string arguments by concatenating different elements.

A concrete formula is a bit hard without knowing your workbook structure.

Assuming that you want to link to the cell on the Domain_master sheet, and assuming that the column "Domain" is in column A on both sheets, try something along the lines of

```
=HYPERLINK("[LinkDemo.xlsx]Domain_master!A"&MATCH(A2,Domain_master!A:A,0),"click here")
```

Adjust to reflect your workbook file name and column structure.